# Setting initial joint position

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How can I specify that my robot model spawned starts in a specific state ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20105/setting-initial-joint-position/) by [gpldecha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6007/gpldecha/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you are launching from ROS,

```
<node name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
  args="-param robot_description -urdf -model robot
        -J ARM/Shoulder/X5_9 1.1" />
```

spawns this *.urdf into Gazebo with the `ARM/Shoulder/X5_9` joint set to an initial position of 1.1 radians.

---

*.urdf (fragment):

```
...
<joint name="ARM/Shoulder/X5_9" type="revolute">
  <parent link="hebi_x5_9_16Z"/>
  <child link="a_2038_02_6Z"/>
  <axis xyz="-2.77554010017e-17 -1.66533454e-16 1.0"/>
  <dynamics damping="0.5" friction="0.06"/>
  <limit effort="100" lower="0" upper="+1.1" velocity="100"/>
  <origin rpy="0.0 -2.77555756e-17 0.0" xyz="-5.63687556453e-17 2.34257058104e-17 0.03"/>
</joint>
...
```

---

Note: If you want to dig deeper, check out these lines in `~/gazebo_ros/gazebo_interface.py`:
https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_ros/src/gazebo_ros/gazebo_interface.py#L38-L51

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) with karma: 609 on 2018-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1